# Convert every option to the same object I get with the ":selected" selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The user can select an option and it will be added to a list.

It looks something like this.

```
<select id="dropdownlist">
<optgroup label="Group1">
    <option value="abc" data-id="11" data-isXX="true" >Text1</option>
    <option value="def" data-id="12" data-isXX="false" >Text2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group2">
    <option value="ghi" data-id="13" data-isXX="true">Text3</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I need the data attributes of each option. This varies from list to list, so I can't query them directly, I always need all of them.

This works quite well because I use the":selected" selector and then simply get all data attributes with".data()".

I want to have a feature that allows the user to add all options at once.
If I now call all options there is no "data()" function, because unlike the selected selector it does not return a jQuery object.

I wanted to make a "each" loop in which I simply pass every option to my existing functions and everything will go through as before.

That's how I imagine it:

```
$("#dropdownlist option").each(function (i, o) {
        var convertedOption = o.ConvertTo
        myfunction(convertedOption);

    })
```

Is there a way to convert every option to the same object I get with the":selected" selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the individual elements into a jQuery object and `data()` will work:

```js
let dataAttrs = [];
$("#dropdownlist option").each((i,o)=>{
  dataAttrs.push($(o).data());
})
console.log(dataAttrs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdownlist">
<optgroup label="Group1">
    <option value="abc" data-id="11" data-isXX="true" >Text1</option>
    <option value="def" data-id="12" data-isXX="false" >Text2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group2">
    <option value="ghi" data-id="13" data-isXX="true">Text3</option>
</optgroup>
  </select>
```